# Cannot See Why SQL is Searching a Discriminator Column

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

After having read a swag of SO questions about the Invalid Column Discriminator, I cannot see why I am running into the issue.

I have reverse-engineered a database Code-First using the EF Power Tools Visual Studio extension.

I have got an include path of "OrderRow.OrderRowOptions.Option" coming off my Orders DbSet. That is,

```
context.Orders.Include("OrderRow.OrderRowOptions.Option")
```

There is no Discriminator column on any of the tables and no Discriminator property in any of my POCOs.

The SQL which is being generated and sent to the database includes a Discriminator column.

Why? It's not like they are out of sync. I've repeated the reverse-engineering in a Console app just to make sure of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have finally figured out the problem here.
I always knew from the outset that it was related to EF's treatment of lookup tables.

And I knew that the Table Per Heirarchy ("TPH") feature was in play here.

The bit that I did not realize what that there does not actually need to be a Discriminator column.

I do have a TPH as there is a type called AdditionalLocationsOrderRowOption which inherits from OrderRowOption.

So, even though there is NO Discriminator column in either my database of my domain types (I've verified this countless times), the TPH is coming into play and preventing me from doing the Include on the Orders items.

So, my next step will be to use the Join method of EF-to-entities.